# Linear independence in 3-space

Tags: topological-vector-spaces

The orthogonal orthonormal basis vectors $i,j,k$ in $3$-space are generally accepted as linearly independent.

However $j$ can be derived from $i$, by the process of differentiation, and likewise vector $k$ can be derived as a *binormal vector* to both vectors $i$ and $j$.

This then questions the notion of independence between orthonormal vectors.
What is it that is missing from this seemingly contradictory situation.
Is there something in the definition of *"linearity"* which is the crucial factor?
Can someone please clarify?

Many thanks.

Comment: ??????? $\bf i$ is a *constant* vector. **How** $\bf j$ can be  "derived from $\bf i$, by the process of differentiation"? And even *if* true (how?), irrelevant. Read again the *definition* of linear independence.

Comment: I accept your line of reasoning. Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be slighly confuzed when you are writing about the vectors. You say that $j$ can be derived from $i$ by the process of differentiation, which is not true. In fact, $i$ is a constant vector, not a function, you can only have the differential of a function.

As far as the definition of independency goes, you have $2$ equivalent versions:

1. The vectors $i,j,k$ are linearly independent if for any $\alpha, \beta, \gamma\in \mathbb R$, for which $\alpha i + \beta j + \gamma k = 0$ holds, $\alpha=\beta=\gamma=0$ must also hold.
2. The vectors $i,j,k$ are linearly independent if none of the vectors can be written as a linear combination of the other two vectors, that is, there are no scalars $\alpha, \beta\in\mathbb R$ for which either $i=\alpha j + \beta k$, $j=\alpha i + \beta k$ or $k=\alpha i + \beta j$ would hold.

It is easy to see that the definitions are equivalent. It is also easy to see that the orthonormal basis vectors $i,j,k$ are linearly independend, especially using the first definition.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: If the answer is what you need, please accept it so it does not appear among "unandwered" questions.

Comment: I accept your post. Many thanks.

Comment: In that case, you can click the greyed out check mark below the vote number to mark it accepted.

Comment: On reflection, the position of a point on a continuous curve C in 3-space can be expressed as a vector function (e.g. as a scalar multiple of unit vector i.)

Comment: That is true, but has nothing to do with linear independence.

Comment: Am I correct in my understanding that even if we have orthogonality in n-space, between basis vectors, linear independence is still unaffected by its definition.

Comment: I don't fully understand the question here, so I will make a broad answer and hopefully answer what you need. There are two concepts you are talking about. One is linear independence. $n$ vectors are linearly independent if no nontrivial linear combination of them equals zero (see above).

The other is orthogonality. The vectors are orthogonal if their pairwise dot product equals $0$.

Every orthogonal set is also linearly independent (proof is not trivial, but not hard). The converse is not true, for example, $(0,1)$ and $(1,1)$ are independant but not orthogonal.